# Appropriate http responses on exception in REST API

Tags: rest, exception, nancy

In my modules, I would like to be able to throw exceptions when "bad things happen" and have the framework automatically catch and convert those exceptions to appropriate http responses (including status code and payload, if applicable). I know I can do this from my bootstrapper in the OnError function on the pipeline. But is there a better or more established way of doing this?

Here's what I have now:

`pipelines.OnError += (ctx, err) => HandleExceptions(err, ctx);`

And the method:

```
static Response HandleExceptions(Exception err, NancyContext ctx)
{
    if (err is NoAvailableHandlerException)
    {
        return ctx.Response
            .WithStringContents("No handler exists to for the given command")
            .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);
    }

    if (err is UserAlreadyExistsException)
    {
        return ctx.Response
            .WithStringContents(err.Message)
            .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    if (err is NotImplementedException)
    {
        return ctx.Response
            .WithStringContents(err.Message)
            .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);
    }

    if (err is UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        return ctx.Response
            .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }

    if (err is TokenDoesNotExistException)
    {
        return ctx.Response
            .WithStringContents("The token you tried to use is not valid.")
            .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }

    if (err is TokenExpiredException)
    {
        return ctx.Response
            .WithStringContents(
                "The token you tried to use has expired. Please log in to get a new one.")
            .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }

    string exceptionText = AddException(err);
    return new Response()
        .WithStringContents(
            string.Format("The {0} request to '{1}' resulted in an unhandled exception!\r\n\r\n{2}",
                            ctx.Request.Method, ctx.Request.Url, exceptionText))
        .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
}
```

Like I say, this works. But seems like something common enough that I'm probably re-inventing the wheel and just haven't found the right blog site to set me straight.

Comment: I wouldn't use exceptions for that. I'd return the and possibly the string contents from the module. If some of error responses need extra decoration an eye implementation of IStatusCodeHandler for each on those cases would be a good fit.

Comment: @ChristianHorsdal That means that I'm always going to have try catches in my modules. It seems cleaner to me to be able to bubble the exceptions up the pipeline and convert to a response later on.

Comment: There is an element of taste here. I prefer reserving exceptions for really unexpected things. Clients trying to make unauthorized requests, or request to endpoints that do not exist are - to me - things a web site or api must expect. Therefore I would not throw exceptions. But you are right that going this way takes effect all the way down.